# How can I use table name instead of SCHEMA in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER drop_table
AFTER drop on SCHEMA
BEGIN
//codeblock
END;
```

Here I have a TRIGGER that does something when a SCHEMA is dropped in DATABASE. But instead of SCHEMA, I want to put a table name(let's say MyTable) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER drop_table
AFTER drop on MyTable
BEGIN
//codeblock
END;
```

Whenever I do that an error occurs;

> ORA-30506: system triggers cannot be based on tables or views

I would like to know if there is a way to do it my way.

*Thank you!*

Comment: That's what `ora_dict_obj_name` inside the trigger is for -- you can check the value and bail if the table being dropped is not `MyTable`. You cannot make a trigger specifically associated with the dropping of a particular table; that would leave the trigger in an inconsistent state after the table is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.

Create a table, connected as `SCOTT`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

Create a trigger, connected as `SYS`; it'll prevent dropping table named `test` which is owned by `scott` (as you didn't say what is your trigger going to do):

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bd_scott_test
  2    before drop on database
  3  begin
  4    if ora_dict_obj_owner = 'SCOTT' and
  5       ora_dict_obj_name = 'TEST'
  6    then
  7       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Can not drop this table');
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> drop table test;
drop table test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20000: Can not drop this table
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Looks OK; can `mike` drop his `test` table?

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Yes, he can.